# List : index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexoutofboundsexception

here is my code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        python_students = [[name, score]]
    z=len(python_students)
    for i in range(z):
        if python_students[i][1]<python_students[i+1][1]:
            list = [python_students[1]]
        list.sort()
        print(list)  

error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    if python_students[i][1]<python_students[i+1][1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i am literally confused with this type of error , kindly explain and help me with this code.

i am trying to fetch names in alphabetical order from the list

Answer (score 1):

`z` should be `len(python_students)-1`. At the last iteration, `python_students[i+1][1]` goes outside the bounds of the list.

Comment: Consider marking my answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is simplifed code, your code has lots of loopholes. you shouldn't use list to store list elements, since list is build class provided by python. its not good practice. also use append to append elements into the list.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_students = []
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        python_students.append([name,score])
        #python_students = [[name, score]]
    z=len(python_students) - 1
    p_s = []
    for i in range(0,z):
        if python_students[i][1]<python_students[i+1][1]:
            p_s.append(python_students[1])
        p_s.sort()
    print(p_s)
```